# Proof of Fundamental Theorem of Finite Abelian Groups?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

The only proofs I've seen of this tend to involve a few intermediate results and a couple of induction proofs with some clever constructions in them. They aren't hard to follow and they're pretty short, but they do still seem to remove some of the "why it should be true" aspect of it. The result seems blindingly obvious to me from a generator perspective: If a finite abelian group $G$ has generators $x,y,z...$ then any element can be represented by the form

$$g=x^ay^bz^c...$$

And there's an immediate and clear isomorphism from this to

$$\mathbb{Z}_{|x|}\times\mathbb{Z}_{|y|}\times\mathbb{Z}_{|z|}\times\cdots$$

Done. It *can't help* but be true. As far as I can see this is immediately extensible to finitely generated abelian groups as well. But the proofs I've seen, while short and simple enough, have never made its proof seem quite so clear.

Is there some major complication I'm missing here? I don't see anything fishy in assuming the existence of the generators, or proving the form of $g$, or actually constructing the isomorphism. But I assume I'm missing something because I've never seen the result proved like this, even though it's an obvious construction. Is the longer proof for pedagogical reasons (i.e. the lemmas and techniques are useful later), or am I missing a big hole in this proof?

Comment: Yes. It's no isomorphism, but only a surjection (in general).

Comment: @darijgrinberg: Actually it is a surjection in the opposite direction (from the Cartesian product to $G$), and no map from $G$ is defined at all.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: yes, that's what I meant, sorry.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider the group $G=\mathbb Z/2\times\mathbb Z/3\times\mathbb Z/5$ and the elements $x=(1,1,0)$ and $y=(0,1,1)$, whose orders are $6$ and $15$. You can easily check that $x$ and $y$ generate $G$, but there surely is no isomorphism $G\cong\mathbb Z/6\times\mathbb Z/15$, for this last group has the wrong number of elements.

Comment: The complication in the proof resides, precisely, in showing that one can find a generating set which has sufficiently good properties that an isomorphism may be defined. Then you have to prove uniqueness, of course, and that is a different matter.

Answer (score 5):

Your representation of $g$ as a product of the generators might not be unique, so the map you want from $G$ to the product of cyclic groups isn't well defined.

That is, we may have $g=x^ay^bz^c\ldots=x^{a'}y^{b'}z^{c'}\ldots$, and there is no immediate way to map $g$ to an element of

$$\mathbb{Z}_{|x|}\times\mathbb{Z}_{|y|}\times\mathbb{Z}_{|z|}\times\ldots$$